# Linux ubuntu не получается установить

Tags: linux, ubuntu, установка

На компе установлена Windows 10. Создал загрузочную флешки с ubuntu. В биосе поменял порядок, начиная с флешки. Следую инструкции до момента перезагрузки. Происходит перезагрузка, просит вынуть флешку и нажать enter. Делаю. Выводит это[image: Выводит это]
Пробовал не вынимать флешку, отключать вообще жёсткий диск с виндой. Не знаю, что ещё попробовать.

Comment: Видимо вы загрузчик не туда куда нужно поставили...

Comment: Перезапиши флэшку руфусом и попробуй ещё раз.